# Java API to find Memory, CPU and Disk usage by HSQL

Tags: hsqldb

I am trying to find Java API to get the Memory, CPU and Disk Usage consumed by HSQL DB for monitoring HSQL DB. As far as I know, HSQL doesn't have any exposed API.

Can anyone please give some pointers on how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DB are your using?

Comment: You need to write functions in Java and use them from within HSQLDB. http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_routines

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, let me try.